# Solr suggester: distributed search (solrcloud) duplicate results

Tags: solr

I have two shards and am trying to implement the suggester (using solr 4.10.1) using a distributed search over the shards. It seems the suggester runs over each of the shards and joins the result set, leaving duplicates. In my solrconfig.xml file I have the following:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">titleSuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupimpl">AnalyzingLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="lookupimpl">FreeTextSuggesterFactory</str>
      <str name="dictionaryimpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">title_sug</str>
      <str name="weightField">rank</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">shingleSuggest</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>`


<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/suggest?suggest.dictionary=titleSuggester&shards.qt=/suggest&shards=shard1,shard2&suggest.q=an&wt=json&indent=true` results in:

```
{   "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":12},   "suggest":{"titleSuggester":{
      "an":{
        "numFound":10,
        "suggestions":[{
            "term":"an",
            "weight":149,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an",
            "weight":142,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an american",
            "weight":6,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an affair",
            "weight":4,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an 18th century",
            "weight":2,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an 18th",
            "weight":2,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an american hymn",
            "weight":2,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an 18th century drawing room",
            "weight":2,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an 18th century drawing",
            "weight":2,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an american hymn (main",
            "weight":2,
            "payload":""}]}}}}
```

As can be seen above, the result term "an" is returned twice, one from each shard. If I do the same query with distrib=false (
`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/suggest?suggest.dictionary=titleSuggester&distrib=false&suggest.q=an&wt=json&indent=true`), I get only no duplicates, as might be expected:

```
{ "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "suggest":{"titleSuggester":{
      "an":{
        "numFound":10,
        "suggestions":[{
            "term":"an",
            "weight":149,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an 18th",
            "weight":2,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an 18th century",
            "weight":2,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an 18th century drawing",
            "weight":2,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an 18th century drawing room",
            "weight":2,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an absolution take",
            "weight":1,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an absolution take her",
            "weight":1,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an absolution take her to",
            "weight":1,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an absolution take her to sea,",
            "weight":1,
            "payload":""},
          {
            "term":"an affair",
            "weight":4,
            "payload":""}]}}}}
```

Is there any way to remove the duplicate results?

Comment: I'd prefer to do this within Solr, but if I don't get a solution we'll do it client-side.

Comment: @were you able to figure it out? In my case, i get a really high number without `distrib=false` but with `distrib=false` I get the correct count.

Comment: No. At first we just filtered out duplicates on the client, then it became irrelevant because (for the reason found [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6246)) I created a new core for just the suggester, and that I made using one shard. The distrib=false doesn't duplicate results because it takes the results from only one of the cores.

Comment: Seems like the issue is because the Solr router strategy was changed from `composite` to `implicit` in our case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Solr's group feature; add to your query:

&group=true&group.field=term&group.main=true

This will return only one document per identical term, and will return them in the same format as a regular query (group.main=true).

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately adding the group parameters doesn't alter my results.